# Limits of "char" type in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is any way by which one can find out what's the limit of char's in C++ on the lines of those provided for int (`std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`)?

Comment: um... `std::numeric_limits<char>::min()`... exactly the same as for `int`.

Comment: I tried it but go no output :
cout << "\tMin :: " << std::numeric_limits<char>::min() << endl;
cout << "\tMax :: " << std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << endl;

Comment: Streaming a character displays its character value, not its numeric value. You should cast the result to an `int` to see the numeric value.

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes... don't really see why.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Presumably because it shows no research effort (since the answer for `int` and `char` is exactly the same).

Comment: @Mankarse but then there's the twist - since for `char` it also returns a `char`, I can see why a beginner might ask this, even with "minimum" research effort.

Comment: I have upvoted to reduce from the negative score (and added an answer): the function shows a valid source of confusion. @Mankarse, there is nothing in the implementation of std::numeric_limits that would indicate to a beginner "watch out how you display char values using io-streams". This question _does not_ "show no reasearch effort" - just lack of experience with the idiosynchrasies of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 4):

`std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` should work.

If you are printing the value make sure you use it converted to an integer. This is because by default, the C++ i/o streams convert 8 bit integer values to their ASCII counterpart (**edit** they don't really convert like that -- see comment by  @MSalters).

code:

```
static const auto min_signed_char = std::numeric_limits<char>::min();
std::cout << "char min numerical value: "
    << static_cast<int>(min_signed_char) << "\n";
```

**Second edit (addressing comment by @MSalters)**:

> Also, your min_signed_char suggests that char is signed. That is an incorrect assumption - char has the same range as either signed char or unsigned char.

While a char has the same *bit size* (one byte), it doesn't have the same range:

The code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout << "min char: "
           << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<char>::min()) << "\n";
std::cout << "min unsigned char: "
           << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min()) << "\n";
}
```

produces the output:

```
min char: -128
min unsigned char: 0
```

That is, while the *size of the ranges* is the same (8 bits), the ranges themselves do depend on the sign.

Comment: No, the streams don't convert like that. They will convert `char` expressions to the character with the same value, using a codepage which can be ASCII, a superset of ASCII or something entirely different. To see why, check `std::cout << 42;`. Clearly 42 is an 8 bit integer value. But the expression has type `int`, so it's printed as one. Also, your `min_signed_char` suggests that `char` is signed. That is an incorrect assumption - `char` has the same range as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.